# Find string with maximum length of given attribute as string in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to find string with max length of a given attribute of java. I will pass the attribute name as string into the method which will return me the string value of max length.

```
   class Employee {
        private String name;
        private String designation;
        private List<Address> address;
        private ContactInfo contactInfo;
        ....
        getter setter
    }
    
    class Address {
        private String city;
        private String state;
        private String country;
        ......
        getter setter
    }
    
    class ContactInfo {
        private String mobileNumber;
        private String landlineNumber;
        ....
        getter setter
    }
```

I have some data just like below:

```
ContactInfo contactInfo = new ContactInfo("84883838", "12882882");
Address address1 = new Address("city111", "state111", "country111");
Address address2 = new Address("city111111", "state11112", "country1112");

Employee employee1 = new Employee("xyz", "uyyy", List.of(address1, address2), contactInfo);

private String findStringWithMaxLength(String attribute) {
    return employeeList.stream()
            ....
}
```

In above case, if I provide attribute value as "city" then it should return me the value "city111111" because of maximum string length.

If we have child objects and list of objects, how do I traverse with the given attribute.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a method that take a list of employees and a function to get the specific attribute like this:

```
private String findStringWithMaxLength(List<Employee> employees, Function<Employee, String> function) {
    return employees.stream()
            .map(function)
            .max(Comparator.comparing(String::length))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Empty list"));
}
```

and to call the method you can use:

```
findStringWithMaxLength(employees, Employee::getName)

findStringWithMaxLength(employees, Employee::getDesignation)

findStringWithMaxLength(employees, Employee::getAddress)
```

Note that the method will throw an exception if the list is empty, if you wont throw an exception, then you can replace it with `orElse(withDefaultValue)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using reflection but here is a better "typesafe" way.

Let the class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
static class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String designation;
    private String address;
}
```

with getters and let the list

```
static List<Employee> employeeList = asList(
        new Employee("xyz1", "abc1234", "address 123"),
        new Employee("xyz123", "abc123", "address 1234"),
        new Employee("xyz1234", "abc12", "address 12")
);
```

then, you can define a generic function able to traverse any `String` field

```
static Optional<String> findStringWithMaxLength(Function<Employee, String> getter) {
    return employeeList.stream().map(getter).max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
}
```

now, you can apply every getter to that function

```
for(Function<Employee, String> getter: Arrays.<Function<Employee, String>>asList(
        Employee::getName,
        Employee::getDesignation,
        Employee::getAddress))
    System.out.println(findStringWithMaxLength(getter));
```

with output

```
Optional[xyz1234]
Optional[abc1234]
Optional[address 1234]
```

(the optional is required since the list could be empty).

Answer (score 1):

The given answers work fine. I'd like to use an enum in this case. If a method changes in the Employee class, you only have to change the enum, not every call using it:

```
enum EmployeeField {
    NAME(Employee::getName),
    DESIGNATION(Employee::getDesignation),
    ADDRESS(Employee::getAddress);

    private final Function<Employee, String> getter;

    EmployeeField(Function<Employee, String> getter) {
        this.getter = getter;
    }

    public Function<Employee, String> getGetter() {
        return getter;
    }
}

private static final List<Employee> employeeList = Arrays.asList(
        new Employee("xyz1", "abc", "address 1"),
        new Employee("xyz123", "abc", "address 1"),
        new Employee("xyz1234", "abc", "address 1")
);


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Optional<String> longestName = findStringWithMaxLength(EmployeeField.NAME);

    if (longestName.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("Longest name = " + longestName.get());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No longest name");
    }


}

private static Optional<String> findStringWithMaxLength(EmployeeField employeeField) {
    return employeeList.stream()
            .map(employee -> employeeField.getGetter().apply(employee))
            .max(Comparator.comparing(String::length));
}
```

**EDIT** for your city use case, something along those lines:

Add an enum **AddressField** on the same model as the **EmployeeField**

```
enum AddressField {
    CITY(Address::getCity);

    ....
}
```

then add a method

```
private static Optional<String> findStringWithMaxLength(List<Address> addressList, AddressField addressField) {
    return addressList.stream()
            .map(employee -> addressField.getGetter().apply(employee))
            .max(Comparator.comparing(String::length));
}
```

and then add a CITY enum to your EmployeeField enum:

```
LANDLINE_NUMBER(employee -> employee.getContactInfo().getLandlineNumber()),
CITY(employee -> findStringWithMaxLength(employee.getAddress(), AddressField.CITY).get());
```

Comment: Hi Bentaye, thanks for the perfect solution. What if I have some child objects, can you please refer my edited question. Map works fine for class which does not have any other object references or list of objects. Can you please consider this scenario ?

Comment: @AnshuSharma for fields in an object you can simply add an enum, ex: `LANDLINE_NUMBER(employee -> employee.getContactInfo().getLandlineNumber())`
for the addresses, it gets complicated, as you don't just need a getter here, but a function that needs to compare the city lengths of all the addresses.

Comment: @AnshuSharma I added some pointers regarding the city use case. It is not good practice on StackOverflow to edit a question and add more to it. Better create another question for it.